# JsonLD & Schema

Tags: templating, plugins, json, seo, plugin-seomatic

What is the best way to use Json-LD schema in the templates for Craft 3? I would like to dynamically load parts of the info. I know about the SEOmatic plugin but looking for a way to do it on my own.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what it is you're trying to do? You just want to generate your own schema.org JSON LD via Twig?

Comment: Yes, basically. I was wondering if there is a way to load json-ld in the templates. So if I had in the template for a blog article I could put in script tags that had json-ld in it. Then fill out the stuff that would be the same and load the rest dynamically.

Comment: I don't see anything preventing you from doing this in Twig?